# Exporting site from weebly - loss of responsive design?

Tags: html, css, export, responsive, weebly

I exported a site I built on weebly, but the html files that were exported do not have responsive design even though the weebly site worked well on all devices.

Does anyone know if there is a way to retain the responsive design from the weebly site when exporting it? If not, is there a (relatively) easy way to transform a site so that it can work on mobile devices?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the Weebly CSS included in your exported HTML?

Comment: Have you contacted [Weebly customer support](https://hc.weebly.com)?